# Modification of HTTP headers with netfilterqueue and scapy

Tags: python, http, tcp, scapy

I want to change "host" header with my value using netfilterqueue (0.6 - latest) and scapy. This is my iptables rules:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

and I have my code:

```
from netfilterqueue import *
from scapy.all import *

def change(pkt):
    scapy_pkt = IP(pkt.get_payload())
    if scapy_pkt.haslayer(TCP) and scapy_pkt.getlayer(TCP).dport == 80 and scapy_pkt.haslayer(Raw):
        http_content = scapy_pkt.getlayer(Raw).load
        list_of_headers = http_content.split("\r\n")
        new_headers = []
        for i in list_of_headers:
            if "Host" in i:
                new_headers.append("Host: google.pl")
            else:
                new_headers.append(i)

        pkt.set_payload("\r\n".join(new_headers))

    pkt.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(0, change)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
```

But it doesn't work.. And I have no idea why.. 
I was printing the headers before and after my change and the only change is the "Host" header. Soo.. Why it doesn't working? Have anyone any ideas?  :)

I'm using CURL for testing and wireshark for debuging. The request isn't sending. I can't find it in wireshark.

Edit:
I was trying to solve this and I change my code to:

```
from netfilterqueue import *
from scapy.all import *

def change(pkt):
    scapy_pkt = IP(pkt.get_payload())
    print dir(pkt);
    if scapy_pkt.haslayer(TCP) and scapy_pkt.getlayer(TCP).dport == 80 and scapy_pkt.haslayer(Raw):
        #http_content = scapy_pkt.getlayer(Raw).load
        #list_of_headers = http_content.split("\r\n")
        #new_headers = []
        #for i in list_of_headers:
        #   if "Host" in i:
        #       new_headers.append("Host: google.pl")
        #   else:
        #       new_headers.append(i)

        scapy_pkt.dst = 'google.pl'

        del scapy_pkt[IP].chksum
        del scapy_pkt[TCP].chksum
        pkt.set_payload(str(scapy_pkt))
    pkt.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(0, change)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
```

but it still not working. In wireshark I was filtering by HTTP. But when I filter by TCP and destport == 80 I can see packages but destination is to IP from argument passed to CURL not to IP that I inject to packet in my code above.

Thanks for advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here.

[Update: the latest version on PyPI, 0.3, is out-of-date as pointed out in a comment. Version 0.6 **does** implement `.set_payload()`] <strike>Before anything, the library you want to use does not seem to implement `.set_payload()` to alter packets (see [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NetfilterQueue/#limitations)). You may want to use [nfqueue-bindings](https://github.com/chifflier/nfqueue-bindings/) instead.</strike>

First (related to your first attempt), changing TCP payload is hard, if you have to change the **length** of the data (which is the case here, since you attempt to add an HTTP header), since you have to change the sequence and acknowledgement numbers of further packets in the same connection.

To implement this, you have two options:

- Use a transparent HTTP proxy which will modify or add the headers you want, and redirect the connections you want to tamper to the proxy.
- Make sure the changes you make will preserve the size of the data (e.g., replace a header with another one, and pay attention to the length).

Second (related to your second attempt), `scapy_pkt.dst = 'google.pl'` sets the destination of the IP layer (and does not change the data), similarly do IP destination NAT. This is very different and should be easier to do (no mess with sequence / acknowledgment numbers here) but you have to do the same modification in:

- The received packets which do not contain data (your code only change packets with a TCP payload, and hence leave SYN+ACK, for example, packets unmodified).
- The packets you receive (you would also need an INPUT iptables rule).

Comment: Hi thanks for response. Soo.. This library that I used have implemented set_payload() - I'm using 0.6 version, you provide link for 0.3 version.

Hum.. So that isn't so simple that i thought.. Can you have a look at my incoming data modification - http://pastebin.com/u0F6YeCB ?

Comment: I've updated the answer for the first part of your comment. Your code on pastebin attempts to fix the value of the `Content-Length` HTTP header (which is needed if you change the HTTP data length, as opposed to the HTTP headers), but you still have the issue of TCP sequence / acknowledgment numbers which will be wrong after this packet. I think the easier options are listed in the answer (either preserve TCP data length, or use a transparent HTTP proxy).

Comment: Ok, I think I don't understand TCP enought...  sequence number is numberof packet in TCP talk. When I change sequence of one packet I should modify other packet in this "talk" ? What is ACK?

Comment: That is a long answer. Maybe [this article can be a good start](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/)